# Related date fields

Tags: datetime

I have made this 2 fields using the Date module and CCK.

- Field **Date 1** I use to choose the date so I put a popup widget
- Field **Date 2** which I need to be related to the first date field, and to which I have to add 6 months

Is it possible? Does somebody know how to do it?

I've tried to put some token in the "Date 2" field options *Default date* and *Relative*, but I've just had problems.

I've searched everywhere without finding a solution.

Comment: explain you question clearly

Comment: You mean Date2 field's value must be restricted starting 6 months ahead of Date1?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use the [Date Restrictions](https://drupal.org/project/date_restrictions) module and get the date from the first date field as relative for the 2nd one.

From the module's page:

1. Date Restrictions Min/Max

   Restricts valid minimum and maximum values to a fixed date, or relative interval. Dates or intervals may be provided statically in the field instance settings, or obtained from other fields attached to the host entity. Some examples:

   - Reservation dates starting today, or three days ahead.
   - +18 years old.
   - Dates after, or before, 01/01/2000.
2. Date Restrictions Allowed Values

   Restrict allowed values based on a multivalued date field, or the results of a view (not yet implemented).
3. Date Restrictions Host Entity

   Allow restrictions based on fields in the same entity, within the add/edit form. Restrictions are performed live with ajax.